# Planet Bike speedometer won't reset

Tags: maintenance, repair

I have a planet bike speedometer and after the winter season it seems that it is no longer functioning. It will come on when the bike starts to move but I cannot reset it and it seems to be frozen on the stats of my last ride where it was working. Does anyone know if this is a battery issue or just a malfunction of the device. If I have to get a new one how expensive and time consuming would it be to replace?

Comment: Have you looked for a reset pinhole or tried taking out the battery for a while and putting a new one in?

Comment: There is a saying in computerdom:  RTFM -- Read The Fine Manual.  First off make sure you remember HOW to reset it.  I have to retrain each spring since none of the new units are nearly as intuitive as the old Cateye Micro.

Comment: Note that your problem may be that the buttons have developed poor contact.  Simply repeatedly pressing the buttons a few dozen times may fix this.

Comment: Put a new battery in it. That will reset the computer and fix any power related issues.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking the battery out, waiting a minute, then replace it. While you have it out rub the battery on a dry rag to clean it, and clean the battery contacts and inside of the speedo too. If it works after that you have a cheap, easy fix.

The other solution is to buy a new, cheap speedo. You can get speedos from about $AUS10 on ebay, so if your requirement is just speed and distance that's going to be the quickest, cheapest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't got it working, give up and chuck it out.

Instead, get the strava app and run that on your fancyphone.   Not only will it log your ride, it'll let you compare your segments with others.

You may need a handlebar mount for your phone, this is a downside.  Plus my phone only gets 4hours life, so I need a power brick battery too.

http://www.strava.com/